# Cannot install windows XP while running Windows 7 Ultimate?

Tags: windows-7

I've installed windows 7 ultimate on my laptop, but have been having lots of problems with my wifi. Been on numerous sites that indicate a bug with wifi in 7. When i try to reload my xp origional disk it comes ap with no sata hard drive/ HDD installed. any ideas please, I am disabled and rely on my laptop, thanks for your time regards Ross

Comment: by your 'original windows XP disk', you mean a OEM Windows XP installation CD or a system recovery disc provided by the manufacturer?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to Dual Boot the two OS’s?

If you want to install XP over your Win7 You might want to go in to the BIOS and Change settings in the “Storage” -> “Storage Settings”. To emulate your HDD to IDE.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the BIOS setting, since the BIOS may be configured for Advanced Host Controller Interface, which XP doesn't seem to support without additional drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Before you go to Windows XP, it may be worth trying to see if you can update your driver directly from the manufacturer - [Intel](http://www.intel.com), [Realtek](http://www.realtek.com.tw) etc.

Next, was this really the Windows XP disk that came with your machine? I have not seen a restoration disk that did not work with the hardware it was coupled with. Please make sure you are using the correct disk as it sounds like you are using an original XP (pre SP1) on hardware that is newer.

Answer (score 0):

The bug you may talk about is that when you go to suspension,and then you resume your WIFI conection get lost and you cannot connect again until restart.

But i think is a LOOOOT easier to just make sure never go to suspension, and/or try to use the Windows Update and download the fix (it fixed one of my setups, 2 of them it doesnt, you may have some luck anyways) than go back to XP

Besides that bug, i haven't heard of any other, and i was using 7 since beta 1. Please make sure you have the rigth drivers as Will says.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to download a driver for the network interface card (the F6 boot disk), and then press F6 during XP startup to install it.  However, like josecortesp, I recommend you stick it out with Windows 7.

See [my answer to this question](https://superuser.com/questions/69632/ipv4-and-ipv6-not-connected-cant-connect-to-the-internet) on a script I use to reset my wireless card - which works for me so I don't have to restart my computer if the wireless doesn't work after resuming from standby.